# There is such a theorem if three prime numbers say $a,b,c>3$ satisfy the relation $2a + 5b=c$ then $a+b+c$ is divisible by integer $ n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

There is such a theorem: if three prime numbers say $a,b,c>3$ satisfy the relation $2a + 5b=c$ then $a+b+c$ is divisible by the integer $ n$. What is the maximum value of $n$?

Comment: Do you know the answer? This is not a puzzle site.

Comment: No answer was not given

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As another (now deleted) answer points out, $a+b+c=3a+6b$. However, we have some more information: none of $a,b,c$ are multiples of $3$. So $a,b\equiv\pm1\pmod 3$. If $a\equiv-b$ then $c\equiv-a-b\equiv0\pmod 3$, a contradiction. So $a\equiv b\equiv\pm1\pmod 3$. It follows that $(3a+6b)/3=a+2b\equiv a-b\equiv0\pmod 3$, so $9\mid a+b+c$.

It is easy to check that $9$ is best possible: $a=11,b=5,c=47$ gives sum $63$ and $a=13,b=7,c=61$ gives sum $81$; these have no common factor exceeding $9$.

Comment: +1  Sorry, I didn't see your post before posting my (essentially duplicate) answer.  I'll delete mine accordingly.